# Meaning of the '+' in PowerShell new-object declarations

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering how to know when to use the '+' in PowerShell object declarations.

Why, for example, is it:
`$searchFilterC = new-object
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection`

and not:
`$searchFilterC =  new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '+' indicates a nested type, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) for more information.

Comment: More to the point, PowerShell follows the syntax of the CLR bytecode here instead of C#'s.